# Stuck on Splash Page Issue with Moodle Mobile App on Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, moodle

I'm currently facing an issue with the Moodle mobile application I'm developing. When I build my app on Android, it gets stuck on the splash page, and the expected functionality does not work. I have thoroughly tested the latest version of the app from GitHub, as well as a few previous versions, and encountered the same issue in all of them.

I have ensured that my app is compatible with the latest version of Moodle.
I didn't encounter any errors while building the app using Android Studio or any other development environment.
I have tested the latest version of the app from GitHub, as well as several previous versions, and the issue persists in all of them.
I have tried running the app on different versions of Android.
I've made sure that my internet connection is working correctly.
I've tested the app on both an emulator and a real Android device, but it gets stuck on the splash page.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

- I have attempted to run the app on various Android versions.
- I have verified the correctness of my internet connection.
- I have tested the latest version of the app from GitHub and a few previous versions, all of which exhibit the same issue.

[image]

Latest console log;

```
CordovaWebViewImpl    -   D  onPageDidNavigate(--domain--)
PluginManager         -   D  postMessage: onPageStarted
CordovaWebViewImpl    -   D  onPageFinished(--domain--)
PluginManager         -   D  postMessage: onPageFinished
chromium              -   I  [INFO:CONSOLE(4755)] "Page is missing a drawer region", source: --domain--lib/requirejs.php/1697804096/core/first.js (4755)
2023-11-07 15:39:13.009 27526-27526 chromium              -   I  [INFO:CONSOLE(4755)] "Page is missing a drawer toggle link", source: --domain--lib/requirejs.php/1697804096/core/first.js (4755)
2023-11-07 15:39:13.010 27526-27526 chromium              -   I  [INFO:CONSOLE(1089)] "Starting Moodle session timeout warning.", source: --domain--lib/requirejs.php/1697804096/core/first.js (1089)
```

Comment: debug your app and check if there is any error in console.

Comment: I added it to the description.

Comment: not enough info on your debugging, you logcat in android studio should tell you the errors.